# set of volume sliders that are working together in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I want to make a set of volume-like sliders using Jquery. Here is the analogy, suppose that I have n sliders (vertical or horizontal). I want the effect of adjusting a slider affect the other sliders.

The contraint is that the sum of the values of the slider must sum to a 100% at all times.
Therefore, if one slider is set to say 40%, the other sliders cannot not have a cumulative sum greater than 60%.

This means that the sum of all the output of each of the slider must sum to 100% and they must work cooperatively. This means that if one slider is set the other sliders must be constrained visually from exceeding its limits that ensures that the constraint is satisfied.

I already know how to make sliders using Jquery so please help me to figure out how to do a number of slider working in a cooperative manner.

Here is what I have done so far, I have only figured out how to do a slider.

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-ui-1.10.4.js"></script>


        <div id="control1">
            <label for="amount">Set Co-occurence threshold</label>
            <input type="text" id="amount" class="sliderClass">
            <br/>
            <div id="slider-range-max" class="sliderControl"></div>
        </div>

        $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider({
                range: "max",
                min: 0,
                max: 100,
                value: 1,
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                    $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
                }
        });
        $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this:

```
<div id="control1">
    <label for="amount">Set Co-occurence threshold</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" class="sliderClass">
    <br/>
    <div id="slider-range-max" class="sliderControl"></div>
    <div id="slider-range-max2" class="sliderControl"></div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$( ".sliderControl" ).slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: 100,
    value: 0,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value );
        $(".sliderControl").not($(this)).slider("option", "value", 100 - ui.value);
    }
});


$(".sliderControl").first().slider("option", "value", 100); //Make sure the first slider is the max of the sliders, the rest is 0.

$( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-max" ).slider( "value" ));
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U4WD7/2/

Comment: Thanks for the solution but is it possible to make it work for any arbitrary number of sliders. The current solution has two sliders.  This is because in my project. This sliders will be created in  real-time where we do not now in advance how many sliders will be needed.